# Highcharts - Dynamically change chart type and data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, highcharts

A large number of examples can be found about dynamically change chart type or data input. If you want to apply both inputs for the same graph but want to execute separately from each other, there are unfortunately no examples.

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/rkzaotyk/1/) example there are two dropdowns in which one dropdown can select the chart type and in the other the data. I would like that when you select a different chart type that the graph is animated again. The same applies when you select new data. In addition, when you first have to start up, as standard variables are now filled so that you always see a graph.

The data dropdown works. Unfortunately the chart type does not work. This is the only thing that is not working.

HTML code:

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <select class="selectpicker" id="chartType">
    <optgroup label="select chart type">
    <option value="line">line</option>
    <option value="bar">bar</option>     
    <option value="line">line</option>
    <option value="pie">pie</option>  
</optgroup>        
</select>
      <select class="selectpicker" id="data">
    <optgroup label="select chart type">
    <option value="data1">data1</option>
    <option value="data2">data2</option>     
     <option value="data3">data3</option>
     <option value="data4">data4</option> 
</optgroup>        
</select>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="grafiek_bench_rendement"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$(function() {

//create a variable so we can pass the value dynamically
var chartype = 'line';
var chartTitle = 'Browser Chart';
var chartCategories = ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];
var chartData = [{
name: 'Year 1800',
data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
}, {
name: 'Year 1900',
data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
}, {
name: 'Year 2008',
data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
}];

//On page load call the function setDynamicChart
setDynamicChart(chartype, chartTitle, chartCategories, chartData);

//jQuery part - On Click call the function setDynamicChart(dynval) and pass the chart type
$("#chartType").change(function() {
//get the value from 'a' tag
var chartype = this.value;
setDynamicChart(chartype);
});

$("#data").change(function() {
//get the value from 'a' tag
var data = this.value;

if (data == 'data1') {
  chartype = chartype;
  chartTitle = 'Browser Chart';
  chartCategories = ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'];
  chartData = [{
    name: 'Year 1800',
    data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
  }, {
    name: 'Year 1900',
    data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
  }, {
    name: 'Year 2008',
    data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
  }];
  setDynamicChart(chartype, chartTitle, chartCategories, chartData);
  } else if (data == 'data2') {
  chartTitle = 'Monthly Average Temperature';
  chartCategories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  chartData = [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
  }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
  }];
  setDynamicChart(chartype, chartTitle, chartCategories, chartData);
  } else if (data == 'data3') {
  chartTitle = 'Monthly Average Rainfall';
  chartCategories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
  chartData = [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }, {
    name: 'New York',
    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]
  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]
  }, {
    name: 'Berlin',
    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]
  }];
  setDynamicChart(chartype, chartTitle, chartCategories, chartData);
  } else if (data == 'data4') {
  chartTitle = 'Monthly Average Temperature';
  chartData = [{
    type: 'pie',
    name: 'Browser share',
    data: [
      ['Firefox', 45.0],
      ['IE', 26.8], {
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 12.8,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
      },
      ['Safari', 8.5],
      ['Opera', 6.2],
      ['Others', 0.7]
    ]
  }];
  setDynamicChart(chartype, chartTitle, chartCategories, chartData);
  }
});

//function is created so we pass the value dynamically and be able to refresh the HighCharts on every click

function setDynamicChart(chartype, chartTitle, chartCategories, chartData) {
$('#grafiek_bench_rendement').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: chartype
  },
  title: {
    text: chartTitle
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: chartCategories
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'Total fruit consumption'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    //this need only for pie chart
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  },
  series: chartData
});
}
});
```

I have used the following two examples as a guide:
[Example 1](http://theonlytutorials.com/highcharts-dynamically-change-chart-type-jquery/)
[Example 2](http://theonlytutorials.com/highcharts-pass-data-dynamically-jquery/)

Hopefully you can help me to solve this problem!

Comment: in `#chartType` change, you call to `setDynamicLayer` with `chartType` only. I think you need to pass all the params to the function.

Comment: you can also use official example in this case https://www.highcharts.com/demo/chart-update

Comment: @MoshFeu thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @KeesdeJager My pleasure :)